# Error in WooCommerce customer email - payment_method was called incorrectly

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders, email-notifications

I have setup a custom payment method for WooCommerce, I don't have any PHP error during payment process but in received email by customer there is this error:

> Notice: payment_method was called incorrectly. Order properties should
>   not be accessed directly. Backtrace: edit_post, wp_update_post,
>   wp_insert_post, do_action('save_post'), WP_Hook->do_action,
>   WP_Hook->apply_filters, WC_Admin_Meta_Boxes->save_meta_boxes,
>   do_action('woocommerce_process_shop_order_meta'), WP_Hook->do_action,
>   WP_Hook->apply_filters, WC_Meta_Box_Order_Data::save, WC_Order->save,
>   WC_Order->status_transition,
>   do_action('woocommerce_order_status_on-hold_to_processing'),
>   WP_Hook->do_action, WP_Hook->apply_filters,
>   WC_Emails::send_transactional_email,
>   do_action_ref_array('woocommerce_order_status_on-hold_to_processing_notification'), WP_Hook->do_action, WP_Hook->apply_filters,
>   WC_Email_Customer_Processing_Order->trigger, WC_Email->get_content,
>   WC_Email_Customer_Processing_Order->get_content_html,
>   wc_get_template_html, wc_get_template,
>   include('/plugins/woocommerce/templates/emails/customer-processing-order.php'),
>   do_action('woocommerce_email_order_details'), WP_Hook->do_action,
>   WP_Hook->app in
>   /home/username/public_html/site/wp-includes/functions.php on line 5167

And this is code for email content and full code is available [here](https://github.com/bekarice/woocommerce-gateway-offline/blob/master/woocommerce-gateway-offline.php):

```
public function email_instructions( $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text = false ) {

    if ( $this->instructions && ! $sent_to_admin && $this->id === $order->get_payment_method && $order->has_status( 'on-hold' ) ) {
        echo wpautop( wptexturize( $this->instructions ) ) . PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

I have changed `$order->payment_method` to `$order->get_payment_method` but still receive the error.

Could you please guide me to debug it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public function email_instructions( $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text = false ) {

    if ( $this->instructions && ! $sent_to_admin && $this->id === $order->get_payment_method() && $order->has_status( 'on-hold' ) ) {
        echo wpautop( wptexturize( $this->instructions ) ) . PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

Please try modifying like this. `get_payment_method()`